# Read and update data using Hibernate

Tags: java, database, hibernate

I'm newbie using Hibernate, I've read Hibernate can handle concurrency, but I don't know how to apply it in the following scenario:

- In a web project, there are two enities called Invoice and Control.
- Invoice entity has a numeric field named documentno.
- Control has a field named lastdocnumber
- When a new Invoice is created, the lastdocnumber field is read, increased and the new value is updated in database.

When two users create a new record at the same time, the lastdocnumber is duplicated, because the same value is read by the two requests, I tried to create an Utility static class with a synchronized method, but after a search in google I realised that it can be handled by hibernate.

Could anybody give some hint to achieve that?

Answer (score 0):

Make **lastdocnumber** as unique column so it wont duplicate even if two or more users submit at same time -- JR

Comment: This way you get an error for one the two or more users that click it concurrently , but it won't solve the problem exposed.